# Permissions for Custom Alexa skill says - "This voice model does not support permissions"

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have made a custom Alexa skill from scratch in python but I am not able to change any permissions because that page says - "This voice model does not support permissions " . Can someone please guide me how to resolve this issue.

[image]

But in the Alexa document it has shown provision for permissions for custom alexa skill.

[image]

here is the link for the above picture- https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/devconsole/build-your-skill.html#custom-model

Answer (score 0):

Amazon resolved the issue now it is showing the options. I guess they might have changed something.